# Windows Get Device Properties

Tags: c++, windows, kernel, audio-streaming

So I'm trying to understand Windows Kernel Streaming and ksproxy and I'm confused on what to put where I have "SOMETHING". I'm not trying to get a specific property. I want to know how to get properties in general (for example: the friendly name). Here's what I have so far. Btw, as of right now initialize proxy and uninitialize proxy just call CoInitialize and CoUninitialize.

```
cout << InitializeProxy() << endl;

HRESULT rc;
HANDLE device;
KSPROPERTY property = { SOMETHING, SOMETHING, KSPROPERTY_TYPE_GET };
SOMETHING value;

cout << (rc = KsOpenDefaultDevice(KSCATEGORY_CAPTURE, GENERIC_READ, &device)) << endl;
cout << (rc = KsSynchronousDeviceControl(device, IOCTL_KS_PROPERTY, &property, sizeof(property), &value, sizeof(value), NULL)) << endl;


cout << UninitializeProxy() << endl;
```